# Expand navigation menu

Tags: topmenu

I would like that my menu in the navigation is totally expanded. My structure is now

- Category 1

  - Sub cat A
  - Sub cat B
- Category 2

  - Sub cat A
  - Sub cat B
- Category 3

  - Sub cat A
  - Sub Cat B

Now, when I open the menu, I have :

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

I can then open them one at a time and have

- Category 1

  - Sub cat A
  - Sub cat B
- Category 2
- Category 3

How should I do to see the full tree opened when I open the menu?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, what actually do you want?

Comment: just edited in hope to make it more clear

Comment: where do you want to expand it ? In layered navigation.?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use accordion menu

http://designmodo.com/css3-accordion-menu/

Go through the link

Comment: sorry, this is a too general answer, it does not tell me how to apply it to Magento...